# Extra fee on Pincode

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

I want to add extra amount to the total cart value depending on the customers pincode in magento 1.9.x.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirements, but this may work for you :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

check the extension configuration in link.

how it works is by importing a CSV file with zip codes, countries, weight and price. You can use a wildcard ("*") if you don't worry about some columns & it  works based on website scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The extension does half the work. What I actually want to do is " I want to set different shipping charges for different pincodes for different products.

Comment: `different shipping charges for different pincodes` is done, `different shipping charges for different products` also done : [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-and-product-shipping.html) , but you want `different shipping charges for different pincodes for different products` Good luck in achieving this.

Comment: @SaurabhPathak Did you found solution ?

Comment: No, i didnt find any solution.

Comment: @BabyinMagento, url not existed